# Getting 'Error: Syntax error. Missing ')'' in formula but can't find where

Tags: workflow, formula, workflowrule

I am writing a formula that will execute a workflow action to change an ownership of an opportunity to the database. However, if the user making the change on the opportunity is one of three profiles and attempting to change the owner, I don't want to execute this action as it would switch back to database every time, so I am setting the formula explicitly to evaluate to false in this instance. I'm not very experienced in writing formulas and am getting the error in the title when I check my syntax. I matched up all of the parentheses in a code editor so I think I may be doing something else wrong. Here is my formula.

```
IF(
    $Profile.Name = 'Sales Manager' || $Profile.Name = 'Sales Operations || $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' && ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
), false, (
    (
        CONTAINS(Account.Owner.UserRole.Name, 'Direct')
    ) && (
        Stage_Duration__c > 60
    ) && (
        StageName = 'New Opportunity'
    ) && (
        StageName <> 'Launched'
    ) && (
        StageName = 'Post Launched'
    ) && (
        StageName <> 'Lost'
    )
)
```

Comment: a shout out to Chrome extension [Enhanced Formula Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforcecom-enhanced-fo/cnlnnpnjccjcmecojdhgpknalcahkhio) which makes finding unbalanced parens a snap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have a couple things going on here.

1. You're missing a closing quote after $Profile.Name = 'Sales Operations
2. You have a parenthesis that's unneeded after ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
3. You need an additional parenthesis at the end of the formula.
4. While not technically an issue, you have extra parentheses around the CONTAINS() function (and elsewhere)

If you add some formatting, it can help make it more obvious where things have become misaligned:

```
IF(
  $Profile.Name = 'Sales Manager' 
  || $Profile.Name = 'Sales Operations' 
  || $Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' 
  && ISCHANGED(OwnerId), 
  false, 
  (
    CONTAINS(Account.Owner.UserRole.Name, 'Direct')
    && Stage_Duration__c > 60
    && StageName = 'New Opportunity'
    && StageName <> 'Launched'
    && StageName = 'Post Launched'
    && StageName <> 'Lost'
  )
)
```

Comment: Yeah that formatting makes it much easier to spot. Thanks! I'm used to working in an IDE and formatting sort of being done for me so I appreciate the example.

Comment: +1 for the advice for formatting. Newlines and indentation are a very powerful tool for debugging (and not just for formulae, sensible formatting also helps in debugging/digesting Apex, Lightning/Javascript, and Visualforce)

Comment: You could get rid of quite a few parentheses still, which would probably reduce the risk of this type of mistake. Still, hadn't seen you on here in a while. Nice to see you back after a long hiatus. :)

Comment: Good catch @AdrianLarson - I updated the answer accordingly. I'm baaaaack!

Comment: One thing I just noticed, the conditions `AND` join two separate equality checks on `StageName`. They cannot possibly both be true concurrently.